# Datagrid Rows Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, foreach

I am attempting to take the `id` of each row of the datagrid `dgGrid` that has a checkbox selected and place it into an array `ruleids`. I've looked up examples online and noticed that this loop comes up.

when I attempted to reconstruct the logic I get this error:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls does not contain a definition for Rows.

```
  int[] ruleids = null;
  foreach (GridViewRow  gvr in dgGrid.Rows)
  {
       if (((CheckBox)gvr.findcontrol("chkSelect")).Checked == true)
       {
            ruleids.add(gvr.cells["id"]);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Couple issues right off the bat.  Your array `ruleids` does not have a method called `Add`.  So even if the rest of your code was working you would not be able to fill the array that way.  Also in your `foreach` statement, try `DataGridViewRow` instead of `GridViewRow`.  That should take care of the initial error I believe.

Comment: Did you actually try writing this code in Visual Studio?  It seems like a cut and paste from somewhere as the syntax just wont compile as it is now.  Where are you getting `FindControl`?  If I can get this to actually compile, I can formulate a real answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datagrid does not contain a definition for "rows". Instead of rows, it has "items".

So try with Datagrid.items...

```
    foreach (GridViewItem  gvr in dgGrid.Items)
{

    //BLA BLA BLA...
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Which namespace is GridViewItem in ?

Comment: Ok, its the 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls' namespace, but cant add this with the using directive, because 'Type or namespace Windows could not be found'. Do I have to add a reference ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridItem dgi in DataGrid1.Items)
{
   tb.text = dgi.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

I Use this to loop DataGrid I hope to help you.