# Filling Textboxes based on selected record in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Writing WPF application using MVVM pattern.  I have a datagrid bound to data model which creates a collection of data for a search term.  One of the fields I display in the datagrid is a unique reference number.  When I click on a record in the datagrid i want to populate some text boxes with extra data about the person selected using the reference number of that person.

Here is the xaml for my datagrid:

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgPersonal"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding UserSearchCollection}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" x:Name="RefNo" Binding="{Binding RefNo}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="125" x:Name="FullName" Binding="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone"  Width="75" x:Name="Voice" Binding="{Binding Voice}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Preferred First Name" Width="125" x:Name="FirstName" Binding="{Binding PreferredFirstName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Preferred Last Name" Width="125" x:Name="LastName" Binding="{Binding PreferredLastName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DOS" Width="90" x:Name="DateOfSeparation" Binding="{Binding DateOfSeparation, StringFormat=M/d/yyyy}" SortMemberPath="DateOfSeparation" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

Here is the code the does the search from my view Model
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchString))
                return;

```
        var search = dal.PersonalRepository.GetAll();

        if ( Regex.IsMatch(SearchString, @"^(\(?\d{3}?\)?)?[-\.\s]?\d{3}[-\.\s]?\d{4}$") )
            search = phoneSearch(search);
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(SearchString, @"^r?\d+$"))
            search = refNoSearch(search);
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(SearchString, @"^e?['C'||'c']\d+$"))
            search = empIdSearch(search);
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(SearchString, @"^(\w\d{2}|\wDC|O\w{2})(\w{4})$"))
            search = casCodeSearch(search);
        else
            search = nameSearch(search);

        if (!ShowSeparatedUsers)
            search = search.Where(x => x.DateOfSeparation == null);

        //        .Where(p => p.FirstName.Trim().Contains(_searchParam1) && p.LastName.Trim().Contains(_searchParam2)
        //                    ||
        //                    (p.FirstName.Trim().Contains(_searchParam2) && p.LastName.Trim().Contains(_searchParam1))


        UserSearchCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(search.Select(x => new User {
            RefNo = x.RefNo,
            Voice = x.Voice.Trim(),
            FirstName = x.FirstName.Trim(),
            LastName = x.LastName.Trim(),
            PreferredFirstName = x.PreferredFirstName.Trim(),
            PreferredLastName = x.PreferredLastName.Trim(),
            DateOfSeparation = x.DateOfSeparation,
            EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId.Trim()
        }).ToList());
        IsSearched = true;
```

My model is called User and this is what it looks like

```
public class User : ObservableObject
{
    public int RefNo { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string PreferredLastName { get; set; }
    public string PreferredFirstName { get; set; }
    public string Exemptions { get; set; }
    public string Voice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfSeparation { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Caspar { get; set; }
    public string Exempt { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Budcat { get; set; }
    public string Posnno { get; set; }
    public string Rptto { get; set; }
    public string Cascode { get; set; }
    public string Budorg { get; set; }
    public string NTE { get; set; }
    public string FullName {
        get {
            return Utils.FormatFullName(LastName, FirstName, Suffix, PreferredLastName, PreferredFirstName,
                Exemptions);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample of one of the textboxes I want to fill with data when the person is selected in the datagrid.

```
 <TextBox Style="{StaticResource textboxStyleBlue}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: consider refering to this question - it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693479/datagrid-rows-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a binding to DataGrid.SelectedItem:

1. Give DataGrid a Name: x:Name="grid"
2. Set TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=grid,Path=SelectedItem.LastName}

I think, that should work for you.